# After login in take users to certain activities

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a user that has username email password and a permission.
Basically what i want is after a successful login i want to take for example users with permission 0001 to a certain activity and users with permission 0002 to another one.
Here is how i make the log in.But when i try adding something like if permission is 0001 then create new intent i get an error that "invalid email or password"

```
private void verifyFromSQLite() {
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextEmail(textInputEditTextEmail, textInputLayoutEmail, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextPermission, textInputLayoutPermission, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
        return;
    }
    if (!inputValidation.isInputEditTextFilled(textInputEditTextPassword, textInputLayoutPassword, getString(R.string.error_message_email))) {
        return;
    }


    if (databaseHelper.checkUser(textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()
            , textInputEditTextPassword.getText().toString().trim(),textInputEditTextPermission.getText().toString().trim())) {


        Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersListActivity.class);
        accountsIntent.putExtra("EMAIL", textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim());
        emptyInputEditText();
        startActivity(accountsIntent);


    } else {
        // Snack Bar to show success message that record is wrong
        Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, getString(R.string.error_valid_email_password), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * This method is to empty all input edit text
 */
private void emptyInputEditText() {
    textInputEditTextEmail.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextPassword.setText(null);
    textInputEditTextPermission.setText(null);
}
```

Comment: This code seems incomplete? I cant see any reference to permissions or checking permissions? What have you tried already? It will be helpful to see a complete class

Comment: well its a school project the permission is just a number when the user registers he can put that number on his own... so its not really "permission" more like another password i just want users with a certain "password-permission" to go into another intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's quite simple, get the value from the EditText and run a set of condition statements against that manipulate the intent it before activating it:

```
final String permission = textInputEditTextPermission.getText().toString().trim();
final String email = textInputEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

emptyInputEditText();

if (permission.equals("1")) {
    accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, UsersListActivity.class);
} else if (permission.equals("2")) {
    accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, OtherActivity.class);
} else {
    accountsIntent = new Intent(activity, AnotherActivity.class);
}

accountsIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_EMAIL", email);   
startActivity(accountsIntent);
```